# Java iterate through priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to do a while loop that will iterate through a java priority queue and read in top of the queue's date. One it has the date value, looks through the rest of the queue to see if this date is being used elsewhere, if so add these elements temporarily to their own queue so I can call a different comparator method to sort them out.

```
public JobRequest closestDeadlineJob(int freeCPUS) {
    // find top job to determine if other jobs for date need to be considered
    JobRequest nextJob = scheduledJobs.peek(); // return top most job
    // what is it's date?
    Date currentDate = nextJob.getConvertedDeadlineDate();
    JobPriorityQueue schedulerPriorityQueue = new JobPriorityQueue();
    schedulerPriorityQueue.addJob( nextJob );

    while(true) {


    }

    // this is the item at the top of the PRIORTY JOB queue to return 
    // remove that item from scheduledJobs
   // return null; // replace with to the one you want to return
}
```

what I have so far, as you can see not very much

Comment: I don't understand where is the difficulty. scheduledJobs.iterator()?

Comment: Or, implicitly using iterator(), `for(JobRequest job : scheduleJobs)`

Comment: I know that part but I don't know how to say search through to see if the GetConvertedDeadlineDate is the same as any others in the queue then if so add these to a temp queue where I can sort something else

Comment: @kieranbop Do you meant to say; you have to retrieve the nextJob from scheduledJobs based on date priority while performing peek()??

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar basically I've sorted them in date order, now I want to take the peek value of the queue and take its date, and then iterate through the queue to see if any others have the same date, if they do put them in their own queue.

Comment: @kieranbop one more question why peek() not poll() ?? do you want to keep the value in the queue? Since the queue is ordered poll will get  exact nearest value at each time.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I will be using poll() to the value this statements returns later on, this is just a check so that if things finish on same day, I'm taking the right one off, as I compare priorities for ones finishing on the same day

Comment: Finally use iterator in the scheduledJobs queue along with the Comparator :: compare(used while creating this queue)  to know the duplicate (date) jobs.

Comment: I even suggest dont go for iterator(not order based); since your queue is already ordered; poll two jobs check its date if it is same go for next poll; else no other identical date jobs in your queue.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar do you have an example of how to do that so I can try and implement it? or can you adapt what I've put above to try that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Job implements Runnable{

 Priority priority;
 Date dateOccurance;

 public Job(Priority priority, Date occurance){
    this.priority = priority;
    this.dateOccurance = occurance;
 }

 public void run(){
    //Job execution
    System.out.println("executed");
 }
}

enum Priority {
 High,
 Medium,
 Low
}

class JobComparator implements Comparator<Job>  {

 @Override
 public int compare(Job j1, Job j2) {

    if(j1.priority.ordinal() > j2.priority.ordinal()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (j1.priority == j2.priority) {
        if(j1.dateOccurance.after(j2.dateOccurance)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (j1.dateOccurance.before(j2.dateOccurance)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }  
    return -1;
 }

}

public class PriorityQueueTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Date d = new Date();
    Job job1 = new Job(Priority.High, d);
    Job job2 = new Job(Priority.High, d);
    Job job3 = new Job(Priority.Medium, d);
    Job job4 = new Job(Priority.Low, d);    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Date l = new Date();
    Job job5 = new Job(Priority.Low, l);    

    Comparator<Job> jComp = new JobComparator();
    PriorityQueue<Job> queue = 
        new PriorityQueue<Job>(10, jComp);

    queue.add(job4);
    queue.add(job3);
    queue.add(job1);
    queue.add(job2);
    queue.add(job5);


    while (queue.size() != 0)
    {
        Job j = queue.remove();
        System.out.println(j.priority +"     "+j.dateOccurance);
    }
 }      

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to warn the reader that using regular looping/iteration and printing too will mess up the order of the priority queue.

Answer (score 3):

PriorityQueue does not provide you a sorted iteration order. The only guarantee of a PriorityQueue is that extraction methods (peek/poll/remove) will return a smallest element in the set according to your Comparator. If you need a sorted iteration order - use TreeSet/TreeMap instead.

Comment: This is extremely important: looping (`for (el : pQueue)`) or printing (`pQueue.toString()`) a `PriorityQueue` will turn the queue itself to a generic container with no order.